# Jquery change event not changing select options as expected

Tags: jquery

A quick overview before my questions:
 I have a set of `<select>`s, one of which is conditionally populated via AJAX based on the first one's value. Nothing magical. My problem is that when I try to programmatically set the value of the first AND the value of the second, the second is reset to the default 0 indexed `<option>`. I know the selected value is being reset, by observing the code run with breakpoints in the browser.

Edit: I've figured out that an event triggered manually isn't actually triggered until after the containing function is finished. This is why I believed the value was being reset, but really the options were being repopulated.

HTML:

```
<div class="row offset3">

    <select id="select-a" name="select-a">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select-b" name="select-b">

        <!-- AJAX Call fills this in -->

    </select>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="change">Change!</button>
</div>
```

A quick summary of the javascript: Add a change listener to select-a that will get the options for select-b, via AJAX, based on the value of select-a, then on page load call this function to populate the selects initially. This is all working and the AJAX call has been minimized in order to save space and time.

JavaScript:

```
function set_b ( data, edit ){
    var options = "";

    for (var a in data){
        options += '<option value="' + $.trim ( data[a] ) + '">' + $.trim ( data[a] ) + '</option>';
    }

    options += '<option value="Custom">Custom</option>';

    $('#select-b').html(options);

    //Moving the below line from outside of the change handler function seems to remedy the issue for now
    $('#select-b').focus().val(edit);
}

function get_b( edit ){

    var set = { "csrf_test_name" : csrf, "a_type" : a_type, "s_type" : s_type, "g" : g, "is_ajax" : "1" };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: set,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data ){
                     set_b ( data, edit );
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log (ajaxOptions);
        }

});


}


$(document).ready( function(){

    $(document).on( "click", '#change', function(){

        var edit = "Fourty";
        $('#select-a').focus().val('4').trigger("change", edit);

    });

    $(document).on( "change", '#select-a',  function( e, edit ){

        get_b( edit );

    });


    get_b();


});
```

Even though this is working, I feel like this is not the right or best way to do it. So my first question is: Any recommendations for cleaner, less coupled methods to achieve the same result?
Secondly:
What I would expect is the change listener to fire immediately after being called and not after the containing function finishes. Is this normal behavior, and is there anything else that happens similar to this in JQuery that I should look out for?
Any constructive input is much appreciated.

Comment: What options are being returned? I see your `select-a` has values 1 - 6, but in the code calling when you click #change you're passing the value "Fourty". Is "Fourty" a valid value in your AJAX loaded options?

Comment: I have changed the options and the AJAX call to shorten up the example and make it readable. So these areas are mostly irrelevant, but yes the available options being returned include "Fourty", in all its misspelled glory, for this example.